# Error reading from a video file in opencv

Tags: python, video, mp4, opencv

The following piece of code will run forever:

```py
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('./Videos/v00001.mp4')
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS, 20)
kernel = np.ones((3,3),np.uint8)

while cap.isOpened() == False:
    print('file not found')
```

I've checked if the path I gave is fine and it is.

The path:

```
VIDEO
│   README.md
│   video_input.py
│   video_processing.py  the file I am running
│
└───Videos
        v00001.mp4  the file I am trying to read from
```

what could cause this problem?

## Solutions:

The file was'nt running from the `Video` directory.

### Good solution:

instead of './' use the absolute path

### Bad solution:

All I needed to do is to make sure that it will run from there.
I just added those lines at the beginning of the code:

```py
import os

os.chdir(os.path.normpath('C:\\****\\****\\Desktop\\vscode workspace\\cv project\\src\\Video'))
print(os.getcwd())  to make sure that working directory is currect
```

Comment: what do you get when you pass your path into ```os.path.isdir('''Your Path Here''')```

Comment: @KalebaKBKeitshokile by running  `print(os.path.isdir('.'))` i get `True`

Comment: Which IDE are you using. Make sure that you are in the correct working directory

Comment: I am using vscode

Comment: I don't know how to check the working directory on vscode but I if you can ensure that you are in the correct working directory I think that might be the problem

Answer (score 0):

```
('./Videos/v00001.mp4')
```

to go back use ( .. ) instead of single ( . )

try this

```
('../Videos/v00001.mp4')
```

Comment: the `videos` directory and  the `video_processing.py` are in the same directory

Answer (score 0):

From which directory are you running the python file from?
Open the terminal at the `VIDEO` directory, then run `video_processing.py`

Comment: I am running it from the grandfather directory of `video`